# Exception: Unmarshalling unknown type code occurred at run time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, parcelable

I am working on Android app and we are working as a team. I am facing a serious issue. And that is when ever I try to get the data from intent it gives me following exception

> ***Parcel android.os.Parcel@355932a: Unmarshalling unknown type code***
>   ***4784211 at offset 712***

I know on SO there are a lot of helping material related to this issue, but my case is different and quiet mind boggling .....

Here is a quick code to see how I am getting my object

```
       try {
                if (data.hasExtra("KEY_MY_MODEL")) { 

                    MyCustomModel newSelectedModel = data.getParcelableExtra("KEY_MY_MODEL");


                    //DO SOME THING WITH OBJECT
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Case1:**
I am getting exception on first line **if (data.hasExtra("KEY_MY_MODEL")) {**

and this is quiet funny because when I inspect the intent object (data) while debugging and if I look into intent object using debugging I can see all my custom object.

The keys of getting object are same, if in any case the key is wrong I think the code inside the  if condition must not get run. as it will return false.

But instead of returning false it is giving the above mentioned exception.

**Case2:** As I told you we are working in team, the same set of code is running perfectly on other system, but when I run app from my system and install app on device, it is giving the exception I mentioned above.

This is very much frustrating. I think there is something wrong with proguard, as I read on S.O but its still not helpful. Any Idea why this is happening? This looks like a big bug.

> **Note: I am using A.S 3.5 and on other system A.S 3.5 is in use, even we have same set of sdk, configurations and other things are quiet
>   identical on both sides...**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a **ProGuard** issue

Just add this line in `proguard.rules.pro/txt`

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Just cross-check your proguard file with teammates